# Malformed policy document when calling the CreateRole operation

Tags: json, python-3.x, boto3

I am new to python and boto3 so forgive me if this is something simple that I'm missing.

I am trying to create a role in my Lambda function using python and boto3. I have 2 files in my Lambda function, they are: roles.py and roles.config.json. As you can see from the code below I used json.load to bring in the json file. I've tried the following:
1. Using a json formatter and validator
2. Using json.loads, dumps and dump
3. Replacing the single quotes in assume_role_policy to double quotes with 
  .replace (although I'm not sure if that is still a method)
4. Changing the policy (for assume_role_policy) so that it doesn't include 
  "Principle"

roles.py

```
import boto3
import botocore
import json
from pprint import pprint
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import time
import urllib


def lambda_handler(event, context):
# return

with open('roles.config.json') as roles_config:
    config = json.load(roles_config)
    print(config)

role_id = config['role_id']
role_name = config['role_name']
desired_policy = config['desired_policy']
topic_arn = config['topic_arn']
assumed_role = config['assumed_role']
assume_role_policy = config['assume_role_policy']
policy_name = config['policy_name']
assume_role_session = config['assume_role_session']
accounts = config['accounts']
region = config['region']
role_arn_compliance = config['role_arn_compliance']
role_arn_nonprod = config['role_arn_nonprod']
role_arn_demo = config['role_arn_demo']


session  = create_session(role_arn=role_arn_nonprod)
print('session = '+str(session))

# client = boto3.client('iam')
# resource = boto3.client('iam')

client = session.client('iam')
resource = session.client('iam') 


listRoles = client.list_roles()
# pprint(listRoles)
RolesList = listRoles['Roles'][0]['RoleName']

for roles in listRoles['Roles']:
    # print(roles)
    assumes_role_policy = str(assume_role_policy)
    roles_names = roles['RoleName']
    print(roles_names)
    print(assume_role_policy)
    print(type(assumes_role_policy))

    if role_name in roles_names:
        print("All's Well!!!")
    else:
        print("Create another one!")
        print(role_name)

        new_role = client.create_role(
            RoleName = role_name,
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument = assumes_role_policy
        )
        break
```

roles.config.json

```
{
"desired_policy":"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess",
"topic_arn":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:Test",
"assumed_role":"arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/Role1",
"role_id":"AeO4JD56FFWw4SPALPMGS",
"role_name":"sample_read_only",
"assume_role_policy":
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement":
       [
         {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal":
            {
              "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
      ]
  },
"policy_name":"AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess",
"assume_role_session":"AssumeRoleSession",
"accounts":[
   "000000000000",
   "111111111111",
   "222222222222"
],
"region":"us-east-1",
"role_arn_compliance":"arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/Role0",
"role_arn_nonprod":"arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/Role1",
"role_arn_demo":"arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/Role2"
}
```

Comment: I'm having a simular issue where I want to create a policy first and then create a role that ataches the policy. whats the actual error your getting back from boto?

Answer (score 0):

This could be an encoding issue try:

```
with open('roles.config.json', 'r') as myfile:
    policy=myfile.read()
encodedPolicy = urllib.quote(policy)

new_role = iam.create_role(
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument=encodedPolicy,
    Path='/', 
    RoleName=role_name
 )
```